# Crear Date con año en dos digitos

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

para mala suerte mia una API que ocupamos en un proyecto, devuelve las fechas con el formato string `211119`, teniendo en cuenta que esta fecha es `2021/11/19` me gustaria poder crear un objeto `Date` y poder compararlo con otro.. obviamente lo primero que intente es aplicar un `slice`, crear la fecha pero creo la fecha `1921/11/19`.

```js
var fecha = '211119';
var anio = fecha.slice(0, 2);
var mes = parseInt(fecha.slice(2, 4));
var dia = fecha.slice(4, 6);
console.log(moment(new Date(anio, mes - 1 , dia)).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Output:

```
1921/11/19
```

Comment: cuando hay años asi, lo unico que se puede hacer es suponer que se refieren a años de un determinado siglo. Si te definen que corresponden al siglo 21, pues no hay otra mas que sumarle 2000 al año.

Comment: gracias @Klaimmore, vamos a probr con eso!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Javascript, los dos dígitos se refieren por defecto a las fechas entre 1900-1999, [como puedes ver aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Two_digit_years_map_to_1900_-_1999).

Pero con [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com) puedes crear correctamente tu objeto `Date` aplicando el método [`toDate`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) del siguiente modo:

```
var dateString = '211119';
var dateFormat = 'YYMMDD';
var newDate=moment(dateString, dateFormat).toDate();    
console.log(newDate);
```

**Output:**

```
Fri Nov 19 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```